# Is there any possibility of general notification for an android-based WebView mobile application?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there any possibility of general notification for an android-based Webview mobile application?

Hi there. I have built an android based WebView mobile application of Nextcloud. [Nextcloud is a suite of client-server software for creating and using file hosting services. It is enterprise-ready with comprehensive support options. Being free and open-source software, anyone is allowed to install and operate it on their own private server devices.] So the activities in nextcloud will be notified with in the website without any issue.

We wan't the notfication to pop-up, like general Android mobile applications. Can any one help me. First i need an clarification is this possible or not?

While using Chrome, The notifications of any websites will be pop-up in our laptop. Like wise we want the webview to pop-up the notifications in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, your requirement is not possible directly. The web push notification only works for the browser. In that browser will be responsible for showing notifications for the user. For example, let us consider we send web push notifications with FCM. Notification will be sent to Chrome/Mozilla server from firebase and it will be delivering it to devices. The browser is responsible for push notification permission handling.

First, webview cannot handle permission.Webview does not have a push server. So it can not receive the notification sent from FCM server.

Alternatively, you can try with [service worker api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) in webview and handle receiving notifications natively. Web push internally uses manifest.json(To configure notification icon,name,fcm id) and service worker API to achieve push notifications for web apps.

Else you can use try [Trusted Web Activity(TWA)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/). It uses **Chrome custom
tabs** to load the webpage. It required Chrome in the device. Since Chrome custom tabs runs on top of chrome, it can handle push notification delivery.
But not sure whether the notification will be delivered via chrome or the app. If your app is a PWA and it uses TWA, a notification might get delivered to your app. Otherwise, it might get delivered through the Chrome browser